# Correctly setting the start and end index for each batch when running new data through a classification checkpoint

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I have a checkpoint loaded and am attempting to test it out by running batches through it. The entire code is here. Where I'm hoping for guidance is how predict over all examples (500) using the batch loop as defined below. I thought I would be able to achieve this by defining `batch_start` *and* `batch_end` as they are, starting at the first element in the index and working its way through until all examples are labeled. The issue I'm unable to resolve is that this code is only inferring on the last 4 examples (496:499) of the dataset.

```
id2label = {0: "billing", 1: "feedback", 2: "account", 3: "newsletters", 4: "other", 5: "tech_issue", 6: "home_delivery", 7: "access", 8: "cancel"}



tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
# Load the configuration for the model
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased",num_labels = 9,ignore_mismatched_sizes = True, max_length=250)

# Load the checkpoint weights into the model
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('/content/drive/MyDrive/category_class_chkpt0'), strict=False)


batch_size = 16  
max_length = 200 

num_samples = len(new_data)
num_batches = (num_samples + batch_size - 1) // batch_size

predicted_labels = []

for i in range(num_batches):
    batch_start = i * batch_size
    batch_end = min((i + 1) * batch_size, num_samples)

    tokenized_data = []
    for index in range(batch_start, batch_end):
        row = new_data.iloc[index]
        text = row["transcript"]  
        tokens = tokenizer.encode_plus(text, truncation=True, padding="max_length", max_length=max_length, return_tensors="pt")
        tokenized_data.append(tokens)


input_ids = torch.cat([data["input_ids"] for data in tokenized_data], dim=0)
attention_masks = torch.cat([data["attention_mask"] for data in tokenized_data], dim=0)


outputs = model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_masks)
predictions = outputs.logits.argmax(dim=1)

predicted_labels = [id2label[label.item()] for label in predictions]
```

The output of the above code when run is. How can I adjust the batch logic to ensure I'm able to run through the entire dataframe?

```
print(predictions)

returns 

tensor([0, 0, 0, 6])
```